# Need help to derive the conditional pdf

Tags: self-study, random-variable, density-function

I am fighting to understand a perhaps simple question, described below.

Let $X$ be a positive continuous random variable. Now, define another random variable
$$
Y = \begin{cases}
\text{undefined} & \text{ if } X \leq d \\
X - d & \text{ if } X > d
\end{cases} \> .
$$

Now my job is to calculate the pdf of $Y$.

My friend calculates:
$$
\frac{f(y+d)}{1 - F(d)} ,\quad y > 0,
$$
where, $f$ and $F$ are the pdf and cdf of $X$, respectively.

What is bothering me is:
**Should it not be, instead,**
$$

\frac{f(y+d)}{1 - F(d)} ,\quad y > d \> ?
$$

What I am missing here? I would really appreciate if somebody explain me in some easy way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You also have to define $Y$ when $X\leq d$ otherwise $Y$ is not a well-defined random variable. For example set $Y=\infty$ when $X\leq d$. Whatever your choice is, $Y$ no longer has a density because it has an atom at $\infty$ (or at $a$ if you set $Y=a$ when $X\leq d$, whatever the choice of $a$).
You can write the distribution of $Y$ as a weighted sum of a Dirac distribution at $\infty$ and a continuous distribution on $[0, +\infty[$ : the distribution of $Y$ is $$p\delta_\infty + (1-p) g(y)dy$$ where $p=\Pr(X\leq d)=F(d)$, $\delta_\infty$ is the Dirac mass at $\infty$ and $g(y)dy=\Pr(Y \in dy \mid X>d)=\Pr(X-d \in dy)/\Pr(X>d)=\frac{f(y+d)}{1-F(d)}dy$.

Comment: Wellcome, Stéphane. There are some osbcure points in your answer, I think by $Y \in dy$ you mean $Y \in [y, y+ dy]$. Moreover $g(y)$ have to be null when $y < 0$. Finally, there is a simplification between $1-p$ and $1-F(d)$, which should be explicited...

Comment: With $Y = \infty$ if $X \leq d$, the cumulative distribution function $F_Y(y)$ does not have the property $$\lim_{y \to \infty} F_Y(y) = 1$$ which is commonly attributed to distribution functions. Also, $Y$ does not have an expectation or any other moments etc. So, is it worthwhile using $\infty$ as an _example_ of a possible definition of the value of $Y$ when $X \leq d$ when a finite value (as Elvis has used) is so much more convenient (and has common properties that $Y = \infty$ does not share)?

Comment: Yes, your comments about the choice $Y=\infty$ make sense. But I really use the notation $Y\in dy$, see my answer in this post http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/18222/what-does-jaynes-continous-pdf-notation-gxdx-actually-mean

Comment: Is this notation used anywhere else?

Answer (score 5):

Stéphane is right to say that $Y$ cannot stay undefined, you have to give a value to $Y(\omega)$ for all $\omega\in\Omega$.

Stéphane’s choice of $Y = \infty$ when $X \le d$ is a bit difficult to handle even if it is natural. Let’s take $Y = y_0\in\mathbb R$ when $X \le d$. You have,
$$\begin{align*}
 \mathbb P( Y \le y ) &= \mathbb P( y_0 \le y \cap X \le d \cup X-d \le y \cap X > d ) \\
 &= \mathbb P( y_0 \le y \cap X \le d) + \mathbb P(d < X \le y+d) \\
 &= \mathbb P(X\le d) \cdot 1_{y_0\le y} + \left\{\begin{array}{l}
  0 \text{ if } y < 0 \\
  F(y+d)-F(d)  \text{ if } y \ge 0.
  \end{array}\right.
\end{align*}$$
This cdf has no derivative in $y = y_0$, hence strictly speaking no density.

However defining $g(y)$ by
$$g_0(y) =\left\{\begin{array}{l}
  0 \text{ if } y < 0 \\
  f(y+d) \text{ if } y \ge 0,
  \end{array}\right. $$
(the derivative of the pdf "ignoring" the step in $y_0$) and $p = \mathbb P(X>d) = 1 - F(d)$, we can write the density of $Y$ by the mixture 
$$g(y) = g_0(y) + (1-p) \cdot \delta(y-y0)$$ 
where $\delta$ is the [Dirac function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function).

Note that the integral $\int_{-\infty}^\infty g_0(y) \mathrm dy$ is equal to $p$ and by convention the integral of the $\delta$ function is 1, so $\int_{-\infty}^\infty g(y) \mathrm dy = 1$.

**Edit 1** you can chose $y_0 = +\infty$ is you wish, in that case there is a Dirac mass in $+\infty$. I don’t know if there is some standard notation for this.

**Edit 2** I suspect that the original question was to give the density of $Y$ *conditional to $X>d$.*

In that case you don’t need bother with the values taken by $Y$ when this condition is not fulfilled. You can write

$$\begin{array}{rcl}
 \mathbb P( Y \le y | X > d) &=& { \mathbb P(X \le y+d \cap X > d) \over \mathbb P(X>d)} \\
 &=& \left\{\begin{array}{l}
  0 \text{ if } y < 0 \\
  {F(y+d)-F(d)\over 1 - F(d)}  \text{ if } y \ge 0,
  \end{array}\right.
\end{array}$$
and the density of $Y$ conditional to $X>d$ is 
$$g(y|X>d) = \left\{\begin{array}{l}
  0 \text{ if } y < 0 \\
  {1\over 1-p}f(y+d) \text{ if } y \ge 0.
  \end{array}\right. $$

As whuber pointed out in the comments, a natural interpretation of this is to change the sample space $\Omega$ to $\Omega' = \{ \omega \in \Omega \>:\> X(\omega) > d \}$.

Comment: I agree that $Y = \infty$ as Stéphane has chosen is a little trickier to handle.  Also, some people like to _define_ random variables as mappings from the sample space to the real line instead of the _extended_ real line, and in that sense, Stéphane's $Y$ is not a random variable at all.  While arbitrary $y_0$ as you have chosen has no problems, a very natural choice is $Y = 0$ if $X \leq d$ and $Y = X-d$ if $X > d$ so that $Y$ takes on values in $[0,\infty)$.

Comment: Yes, my opinion is that Bogaso forgot to write a part of the question... my intuition is that it is "the pdf of $Y$ conditional to $X > d$".

Comment: Another approach is to view $Y$ as a random variable on a different but related sample space, $\Omega'=\{\omega\in\Omega\ |\ X(\omega)\gt d\}$.  (This would be a good model for rejection sampling for instance.)  This avoids all the considerations mentioned here and in Stephane's reply, which are incidental and distracting anyway.

Comment: @whuber Thanks, I added a second edit... for me this is the pdf conditional to $X>d$!

Comment: Edit 2 clearly answers the question (+1).

Comment: Thanks Elvis for your detailed answer. However I am struggling to understand this calculation:

$\begin{array}{rcl}
 \mathbb P( Y \le y ) &=& \mathbb P(X \le y+d \cap X > d \cup y_0 \le y \cap X \le d) \\
 &=& \mathbb P(X\le d) \cdot 1_{y_0\le y} + \left\{\begin{array}{l}
  0 \text{ if } y < 0 \\
  F(y+d)-F(d)  \text{ if } y \ge 0.
  \end{array}\right.
\end{array}$

Especially how I should convince myself (preferably in plain English) on how I get the 3rd line. Can you please help me?

Comment: @Bogaso I added an intermediate line to make it more readable. I hope this helps. In short, $Y \le y$ occurs in two incompatible ways: either $X \le d$ and $y_0\le y$, or $X > d$ and $X - d \le y$. The first possibility has proba $\mathbb P(X\le d) 1_{y_0\le y}$, the second can be rewritten $d < X < d+y$ and has proba $F(y+d) - F(d)$ if $y >0$, $0$ else. Is that better? The quantity $1_{y_0 \le y}$ is $1$ when $y_0 < y$, and 0 else. It could be written $H(y - y0)$, where $H$ is the Heaviside function, the derivative of which is Dirac delta function.

Answer (score 3):

A simple explanation for why your friend is correct - $y > 0$ - is to see what happens to $y$ as $x \to d$ from above.  Since $y = x - d$, as $x \to d$, by subtracting $d$ from both sides of $x \to d$, we get $x - d \to 0$.  Since $y = x - d$, $y$ can get arbitrarily close to $0$, so the lower bound on $y$ is 0, not $d$.